# Double buffered sprite issue in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sprite

Unfortunately, taking a screenshot does no replicate the problem, so I'll have to explain.

My character is a QUAD with a texture bound to it. When I move this character in any direction, the 'back end' of the pixels have a green and red 'after-glow' or strip of pixels. Very hard to explain, but I am assuming it is a problem with the double buffering. Is there a known issue associated with moving sprites and trailing pixels?

Comment: Not really, and without any more details, it's hard to diagnose. My only guess at this point is that you are only using a subset of the texture (i.e. your UVs are not just 0 and 1), and you have some colored pixels outside the rect you're drawing, and due to bilinear filtering, you catch a glimpse of them. Again, without any information, we can only stab in the dark.

Comment: I'll investigate this. Unfortunately a screen-cap of the issue doesn't pick it up.

Comment: CRT or LCD?  If LCD, what's the pixel refresh rate?

Comment: @Headspin: You're redrawing the whole scene, or just trying to move the sprite without redrawing the rest of the scene? If the latter, that's your problem. In OpenGL always readraw the whole thing.

Comment: I am redrawing the entire screen at the end of my loop.

Comment: Are you clearing the color buffer between renders? =/

Comment: @Headspin Could that be subpixel rendering occurring? Is your character being aligned to screen coordinates? I tend to see such artifacts when rendering bright colours on a black background.

For rendering sprites I typically perform scale so that I can draw a triangle strip with integers. The same can be done to store Non-Power-Of-2 textures in a (2^m,2^n) sized image, applying a scale to the Texture Matrix Stack.

Comment: @EboMike If you would like to submit your reply as an answer, that ended up being the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My only guess at this point is that you are only using a subset of the texture (i.e. your UVs are not just 0 and 1), and you have some colored pixels outside the rect you're drawing, and due to bilinear filtering, you catch a glimpse of them.

When creating textures with alpha, be sure to create an outline around the visible part of the texture with the same color (i.e. if your texture is a brown wooden fence, make sure that all transparent pixels near the fence are brown too).

NOTE that some texture compression algorithms will remove the color value from a pixel if it is entirely transparent, so if necessary, write a test pixel shader that ignores alpha to make sure that your texture made it through the pipeline intact.